# Where do i put Main method in a console app that uses the "Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).Build();"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, console

I'm creating a console-app following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration

- Do I put my Main method where it says "// Application code should start here.
  "?
- Do I use a Main method, or how do I solve this?

My existing structure:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            //application logic......
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: The sample you've referred to just uses top-level statements in C# - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements. That *is* the Main method, basically.

Comment: Great thanks. THen, when i have from the past public static async Task Main , the await host.RunAsync(); will make sure it runs in async mode?

Comment: Given that you can only use `await` inside an `async` method, if you use `await` and it compiles then that must be the case.

Comment: One more question; how/where do i add  IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();? Do i add it under/inside ConfigureAppConfignuration ?  I got so cofused :s

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve by creating a new service collection. The host already has one.

Comment: I'm trying to use the IOptionsPattern with my app. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options And that seems to be working. However, the business logic calls an API and when i put the API call "Result result = await client.GetData(options)" i now get: "The await operator can only be used withing a async lambda expression". And if i put it where the template says "Application code goes here", i then my custom ApiQueryClinet is not reachable event though its added to servicecolletion and build to serviceprobider inside the "ConfigureAppConfiguration". How to solve this async

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to create an explicit `Main` method. C# [top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements) mean that the three lines of code from the tutorial:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).Build();
await host.RunAsync();
```

... already form a valid program. It's roughly equivalent to:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).Build();
        await host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

I'd encourage you to use the existing top-level statement approach unless you *need* more complexity in your initialization code... although you *can* write the class and `Main` method declarations explicitly if you want to.

Later examples in the same tutorial show larger amounts of application startup code, still using top-level statements. Or you can just create a new ASP.NET Core application which will show more.

Comment: But if I want to use `IHost` with an existing console application (e.g. with its own `Main` method already) then how do I pass control into that method? When I run the code in your post in Linqpad it just enters `RunAsync` and never returns.

Comment: @Dai: You register an `IHostedService`, which is then called by `RunAsync`. (That will need to be rewritten slightly to be asynchronous.)

Comment: A user-interactive console application doesn't really fit into the `StartAsync`/`StopAsync` design of `IHostedService` though. (But good news: I did find a solution in the end: to use `await host.StartAsync()` instead of `await host.RunAsync()` and then call my old `Main` method right afterwards - followed by `await host.StopAsync()`.